# TFS 2018 build server drop - how do I get the output?

Tags: .net, tfs

I'm new to setting up TFS build.  We have a fresh 2018 SP1 install on prem with an agent on the same machine.  I'm doing some test builds and the drop location is set to "Server".  So once the build is complete, where exactly do I get my output?  Previously we were on 2012 and outputting to a share which I know I can do here, but I've read that server drops are easier/better... but never a mention of how I download the zip file.

Comment: If i do a fileshare instead of a server drop, I see an "artifacts" link in the build details.  That doesn't show for the server drop though ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a PowerShell script to provide the actual paths for all the variables.  I used that to find the intermediate files.  The issue was that the pattern matching int the copy file task wasn't finding the files.  I had to modify the paths and correctly define the variables to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Release definitions will automatically download the build artifacts at the start of the deployment process.

If you need to manually download the build artifacts, you can click on the "Artifacts" view of a completed build and click the "Download" link from there. There is also a REST API available to download an artifact from a build.

Comment: So I would have to set up a release then?  We don't currently use that and I'm not sure it would fit with our business model.  I don't see an "Artifacts" link in the build details though.  If I change it to build to a UNC path, I do have the artifacts link.

Comment: It's entirely possible the "publish" step isn't finding any artifacts to publish, then. IIRC, the UNC path will always be created regardless of whether there are actual files to publish. Could be wrong on that, though.

Comment: Yes, I think that might be the case here for some reason.